# Disable auto play on JSSOR Full Width Slider

Tags: jssor, autoplay

I've tried

`$AutoPlay: false,`

in

`var options = {`

is there something I must delete ?

Answer (score 0):

Please just replace `$AutoPlay: true` with `$AutoPlay: false`

```
var options = {
    $FillMode: 2,
    $AutoPlay: false,
    $Idle: 4000,

    $ArrowKeyNavigation: true,
    $SlideEasing: $Jease$.$OutQuint,
    $SlideDuration: 800,
};
```